# 11:25:00 AM this is my string how do I convert string to java script time format?

Tags: javascript, string, datetime

When I try to convert this using Date , it gives me 'invalid date', I want my string in time or date time format.

Comment: moment.js is what you need for time

Comment: @depperm: Not necessarily.